# Future throwing TimeoutException everytime once it Timesout

Tags: java, future, executorservice, timeoutexception

I am using the following code:

```
import java.util.concurrent
     senderSocket.send(datagramPacket);
            while (!test(packetToSend)) {
                senderSocket.send(datagramPacket);
            }

public boolean test(Packet sentPacket) {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Callable<Packet> callable = new Callable() {

            public Packet call() throws Exception {
                //do operations you want
                Packet responsePacket = Helper.recievePacket(rSocket);
                while (responsePacket.isCorrupt() || responsePacket.getSequence() != sentPacket.getSequence()) {
                    responsePacket = Helper.recievePacket(rSocket);

                }
                System.out.println(new String(responsePacket.getData(),UTF_8));
                return responsePacket;

            }
        };
        Future<Packet> future = executor.submit(callable);
        try {
            future.get(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            return true;
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            System.out.println("time-out");
            executor.shutdown();
            return false;

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The above code runs fine if there is no time-out. But once it throws a  timeoutexception all further calls automatically gets timed out even though I am getting the response. I tried increasing the timeout from 1 sec to 2 sec. It again keeps on throwing TimeoutException

Comment: Submit the same Callable again and assign `future` to the result.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I can do  `future = executor.submit(callable);` inside the catch block But now in the case of TimeOutException, this behavior won't occur again. Basically, when timeout happens it should again do `senderSocket.send(datagramPacket);
                                future = executor.submit(callable);
`   I am not sure how to do this type of stuff

Comment: You have to do a loop that keeps going until success.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Thanks for that. I got something working. But I am getting weird behavior.  `future. get(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);` Once the future times out. It's timing out every time. Not sure why that could be the case. I just updated the code in OP. The logic is working. But the only issue is when a timeout happens. It just throws timeoutexception everytime

Comment: If you timed out, then you did not receive the expected response.  Is it still sitting in the socket? Can the remote end process another request while the response is still pending?   I'd look at what is going on in the 'while' loop in the task.

Comment: I will try to debug it that way. But the weird part is the callable is returning the result. How can future timeout. The code prints the value `System.out.println(new String(responsePacket.getData(),UTF_8));` instantly and then if I give a timeout of even 10 seconds it still keeps on throwing Timeoutexception

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you check with futureisDone(). It is non blocking api. If it return true then you can call future.get()

Answer (score 0):

Java's Future has missed some useful methods like onComplete().
But we can write it by ourselves.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    Future<String> f = null;
    
    onComplete(f, System.out::println);
}

static <T> void onComplete(Future<T> f, Consumer<T> callBack) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    while(!f.isDone()) {}
    callBack.accept(f.get());
}
```